# django rest-frame work jwt athentications fails although I sent correct token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I can receive valid access and refresh token after I logged in to my login endpoint API.

for some views, I have given is_authenticate permission where after providing a valid token, the user can get access to that view. the problem is although I provide a valid token, still it tells me

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

how can I solve the issue. here is my code.

settings. py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin' ,
    'django.contrib.auth' ,
    'django.contrib.contenttypes' ,
    'django.contrib.sessions' ,
    'django.contrib.messages' ,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles' ,
    'rest_framework' ,
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist' ,
    'bd_api' ,
    'op_api' ,
    'drf_yasg' ,
    'django_filters' ,
    'corsheaders' ,
    ]
SITE_ID = 1
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'error',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    }
# for jwt
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME' : datetime.timedelta(minutes=3) ,
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME' : datetime.timedelta(days=1) ,
    }

# swagger
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS' : {
        'Bearer' : {
            'type' : 'apiKey' ,
            'name' : 'Authorization' ,
            'in' : 'header'
            }
        }
    }
```

views.py

```
class op_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet) :
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Op.objects.all().filter()
    serializer_class = op_Serializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication , SessionAuthentication , BasicAuthentication]
    # pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    # pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend , SearchFilter , OrderingFilter]
    filter_class = op_filter
    ordering_fields = ['close_date' , ]
    ordering = ['close_date']
    search_fields = ['website' , 'title' , 'description' , 'organization__name']

    @action(detail=True , methods=['Get'])
    def attachments(self , request , pk) :
        op = self.get_object()
        links = Attachments.objects.filter(op_id=op.id)
        serializer = attachments_Serializer(links , many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class op_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    attachments = attachments_Serializer(many=True , required=False)
    countries = country_Serializer(many=True , required=False)
    sectors = sector_Serializer(many=True , required=False)

    class Meta :
        model = Op
        fields = ['id' , 'website' , 'op_link' , 'title' , 'description' , 'organization' , 'close_date' ,
                  'created_at' , 'relevancy' , 'published_date' , 'language' , 'is_open' , 'read_status' ,
                  'attachments' , 'countries' , 'sectors']
        depth = 2
```

here is how i get the token after login request.

```
{
  "email": "talibacademic@gmail.com",
  "username": "talibacademicc",
  "tokens": {
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTkxODQxNiwianRpIjoiZmY3MTVhY2NlMzQ2NGZjZmFiZGI3ZWZhYjg2MzFlNWUiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxOH0.G0GVjJtAYNXPaVhDlPGJX2JbCzRjHBZc-UXNACNLqj4",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjA5ODMyMTk2LCJqdGkiOiJlY2Q3MTA3ZWI1YmI0Yzc4OGExNTczYTM2ZDM5NWEyNSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjE4fQ.XBLbbUDfQmm8W-g9OOmLkxyj976MLt-DS0q4un4QiNM"
  }
}
```

i can validate my token in the ui , you may see the picture , means my token is correct, but why I can't get access to the api views providing tokens
[image]

despite the above way, I tried to use django jwt prvided views and API and check if thoese token works, but still get the same error  which is authentication credentials were not provided,

here is the code

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView ,
    TokenRefreshView , TokenVerifyView ,
    )
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('bd_api.urls')),
    path('op-api/', include('op_api.urls')),

    path('', schema_view.with_ui('swagger',
                                 cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('api/api.json/', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0) ,
         name='schema-swagger-ui') ,

    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc',
                                       cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),

    # -------------------------------
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair') ,
    path('api/token/refresh/' , TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify')

]
```

getting the key from api/token and using that key to authenticate does not work, I don't understand why it behaves like this, anyone, please help

Comment: how did you send the request?

Comment: i sent it using bearer token using authorization tab in postman

Comment: try settings authentication_classes to allowAny to see if it's the cause

Comment: no , it didn't help

Comment: @LinhNguyen,if you want i can share you to whole code, i need help why it gives me error,

Comment: @JPG  if you want i can share you the whole code folder

Comment: After adding bearer token using authorization tab in postman, check if the same is reflecting in headers and you are not overriding it somehow.